# OPTION(RECOMPILE) does not work while selecting from a TVF. It does work inside the TVF, why?

Tags: sql-server

I am seeing drastically different behavior between the statements below. The bottom one solved my issue with the optimizer, however, I would think they would yield the same behavior since the UDF is inlined into the executing statement.

**Hint placed on the selecting the function.**

```
SELECT F1 FROM dbo.FunctionReturnsATable(P1,P2...) OPTION(RECOMPILE)
```

**Hint placed on selecting the result set of the Function.(Solved my issue)**

```
CREATE FUNCTION FunctionReturnsATable(P1,P2...)
AS BEGIN
    ...
    INSERT @Result SELECT F1,F2... FROM (<Outer CTE of many Inner CTE's>)AS X OPTION(RECOMPILE) 
    RETURN
END
```

Comment: You should change your multi-statement TVF to an inline TVF. You can't use recompile inside the function then, but you won't need to because it gets expanded into the outer query.

Comment: A multi-statement TVF is *not* inlined in the executing statement; that's where your assumptions go off the rails.

Comment: For completeness, SQL Server 2017 does add [interleaved execution](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/187580/97345) for multi-statement TVFs, but this is still not the same thing as having it inlined (and in most cases still considerably worse than an inline TVF).

Comment: Thanks Arron Bertrand and Jeroen Mostert for correcting a misconception about when a TVF is "inlined". The behavior above make perfect sense now.